# И вновь +/- в калькуляторе

Tags: калькулятор

Я прошу прощения возможно я криво изъяснюсь так я только начала учится..... если что поправьте я ни как не могу добавить в свой калькулятор функцию “+/-“ранее я выкладывала форм а точнее что смогла так как полный контекст почему-то не добавляется....(( я просто даже не знаю гд в моем большом решении  при создании калькулятора ошибка..... может есть какая то формула кода ли что-то типо этого для создания кода  функции “+/-“ заранее благодарю

Comment: Если вы учитесь, то самый простой калькулятор это создать 3 переменные. Два числа и одна переменная символ. И просите пользователя ввести сначала 2 числа в эти переменные потом знак операции. Далее или конструкции `if` или `switch` изучаете и создаете разветвления например `if(символ который ввел пользователь == '+')` то складываете 2 ранее введенных числа и выводите результат. Просто вбиваете в гугл уроки по (язык программирования) и смотрите или видео или на сайте читаете основы.

Comment: Мы тоже не знаем, где ошибка, потому что кода нет )

Comment: "не могу добавить в свой калькулятор функцию “+/-“" - а какие функции там уже есть?

Comment: Это был [ваш вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1231093)? И ваша [правка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/563797) уже с другой учётки? Теперь тот же вопрос уже с третьей учётки? Может начать обучение с прочтение [справки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/asking) и освония навыков по запоминанию данных уч.записи.